# Upgraded Grails app compiles but goes straight to Tomcat 404 Page

Tags: tomcat, grails

I'm upgrading a project with about 1300 classes. The current version that it is on is 1.3.6, and I am trying to upgrade to 2.2.2.

I updated all of the plugin references and then ran grails upgrade. It said that it worked. Then I compiled and ran it and it produced no errors.

The only issue is that when I run it, it goes straight to the Tomcat 404 page. There are no errors, no anything. Nothing in Bootstrap.groovy is being run. I have no idea where to even begin looking as I am fairly new to grails. What would you look for?

A newly created application runs fine.

Comment: What happens if you create a new application and copy-paste your classes? Some must read content - [here](http://pledbrook.github.io/grails-howtos/en/upgradeToGrails2.html) and [here](http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/so-you-want-to-upgrade-to-grails-2/)

Comment: The same thing happens. Default Tomcat 404 with no errors printed.

Comment: Start looking from `target/stacktrace.log` after following the basics of upgrade + @SérgioMichels suggestions, adding [one more to the list](http://naleid.com/blog/2012/05/01/upgrading-to-grails-2-unit-testing/).

Comment: @SérgioMichels copying files into a new project worked. I believe the error was in the BuildConfig.groovy not being properly formatted for the new version, as well as application.properties conflicting with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

- grails clean
- grails refresh-dependencies
- grails run-app --stacktrace

If it still fails:

- Increase the log level to debug
- Compare core dependencies between your app and a freshly create app, and update dependencies as needed
- Check the grails version compatibility of your third-party plugins and third-party dependencies, update as needed
- Repeat the grails clean, refresh-dependencies steps.

If it still fails, delete the `.grails/projects/YOUR_GRAILS_VERSION/PROJECT_NAME` and repeat the initial steps.